# Meaning of "it's the tie to go along with X's tux"

Tags: meaning, metaphors

I found this when learning underscore.js (a programming framework). The introduction says:

> It's the tie to go along with jQuery's tux.

Does it mean that it is to be used along with jQuery or is it a replacement to jQuery?

(jQuery is another programming framework.)

Comment: You wouldn't take off your tuxedo and wear just a necktie to a formal ball, would you? Unless they've completely mixed up the metaphor, they mean it should be used alongside jQuery.

Comment: It's the belt to go with jQuery's suspenders.

Comment: @PeterShor Well yeah, developer might indeed do that. Actually, using underscore.js without jQuery is a valid choice, I believe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A tie may be considered a clothing accessory to a tuxedo, therefore the framework author is suggesting that underscore.js be seen as an accessory or supplement to jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

If you wear a nice smart tuxedo suit, you certainly need a nice smart tie to go with it.

jQuery is the foundation, and underscore.js is the essential cherry on the cake to complete the picture.